# Should this function ("isEmpty") check whether the Object has no parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function called `isEmpty`. Here's what it looks like:

```
/**
 * Returns true when the argument is empty.
 * 
 * We define empty as:
 * - undefined
 * - null
 * - a string with length 0
 * - an array with length 0
 * - an object with no parameters: consider this?
 **/
function isEmpty(arg) {

    return (arg === null) ||
        (arg === undefined) ||
        ((typeof (arg) === 'string') ? arg.length === 0 : false) ||
        ((Array.isArray(arg)) ? arg.length === 0 : false);
}
```

I am wondering, would it be useful to return true also when an object has no parameter (`{}`)?

Comment: You mean when an object has *no keys or values*?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what your use case is?

Comment: Yes. Like `let a = {}; console.log(isEmpty(a))` logs `true`

Comment: Yes, it would depend, but I am thinking more generally speaking. Would there be more cases that could be useful letting it set to true than letting it set to false?

Comment: Question seems ambiguous.

Comment: It should check if the object has no properties if you want it to check if the object has no properties. It should not check if the object has no properties if you don't want it to check if the object has no properties. In other words, it should do whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Would it be *most useful* to consider [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) before modifying the behaviour of a function which might be in use elsewhere? As this question is subjective in nature, I'm going to vote for it to be closed as "primarily based upon opinion", or whatever that seems to have become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. It returns false both for eg. `{}` and `{age:67}`.

If you want to check if the Object has no parameters use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method. It's safer than `for in` loop or `keys()` method because it checks whether the object has got only its own properties defined *(regardless its prototype properties)*.

```
var a = {};
var b = {name:'Paul'};

console.log(isObjectEmpty(a)); //true
console.log(isObjectEmpty(b)); //false

function isObjectEmpty(obj){
  return !Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length;
}
```

If you want to keep your function you can use

```
function isEmpty(arg) {
  if(arg === null || typeof arg==='undefined') return true;
  if(typeof arg==='string') return !arg.length;
  if(arg.constructor.name==='Array') return !arg.length;
  if(arg.constructor.name==='Object') return !Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arg).length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case you can say object is empty if it has no key value pairs inside it. Since array is also an object, you can just check for `typeof arg === 'object'` and then check for length of keys array you get by `Object.keys()`. Also for empty string you can just compare arg to "". Something like this:

```js
function isEmpty(arg) {

return (arg === null) ||
    (arg === undefined) ||
    (arg === "") ||
    ((typeof arg === 'object') ? Object.keys(arg).length === 0 : false);
}

console.log(isEmpty(null));
console.log(isEmpty(undefined));
console.log(isEmpty([]));
console.log(isEmpty({}));
console.log(isEmpty(1));
```

Comment: The question is not **how** to check for an empty object, or how to optimize his code. The question is **should** it check for empty objects as part of some general concept of "emptiness", which has no answer, since it is purely a matter of how the function is to be defined and used.

Answer (score 1):

It can probably be generalized to if the object has [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (or [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for iterable objects)

```js
function isEmpty(arg) { 
  for (e in arg) return false;
  return true; 
}

console.log(isEmpty(null), isEmpty(undefined))
console.log(isEmpty(""), isEmpty([]), isEmpty({}))
console.log(isEmpty(0))              // doesn't work for Number, Boolean, Set, Map, etc.
console.log(isEmpty("0"), isEmpty([0]), isEmpty({0:0}))
```